# Simple string passing through nodes in Bison/Yacc

Tags: c++, string, bison, yacc, stringstream

I have to concatenate strings in semantic rules of my yacc file:

```
%union {
  stringstream sstream;
}
%type<sstream> node1 node2

---

node1
: node2 { $$ << $1 << " goodbye" }

node2
: final { $$ << "hello" }
```

However, as `stringstream` or even `string` are not allowed in unions, I don't find any easy way to mix `char *`, `int`, and make nodes transport a string that I can manipulate everywhere.
How should I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember `bison`/`yacc` details, but you sure can use pointer and `new` it. Just remember to `delete` if `bison`/`yacc` gives you the opportunity.

Comment: That's actually not very easy, as there are many final nodes in which I'll have to instantiate `stringstream` (it's a C compiler)...

Comment: @Idiqual: Who said it would be easy?

Comment: Well, that's what I asked for :)

Answer (score 0):

Its actually not all that hard to keep track of the pointers.  For example:

```
%union {
  stringstream *sstream;
}
%type<sstream> pair node1 node2 final

---

pair
: node1 ',' node1 { *($$ = $1) << ',' << *$3;  delete $3; }

node1
: node2 { *($$ = $1) << " goodbye" }

node2
: final { *($$ = $1) << "hello" }

final
: TOKEN { *($$ = new stringstream) << "TOKEN"; }
```

The one major issue is that this will leak if there are syntax errors in your input that cause values to be thrown away without running your actions.  You can get around that problem by using bison's `%destructor` extension.  In this case you need only add:

```
%destructor { delete $$; } <sstream>
```