# Wrap function instructions by some ASM code

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I'm making a simple C compiler as an homework. I have the following grammar rule:

```
function_definition
: type_name declarator compound_statement
```

My semantic rules should transform it into:

```
declarator:
  push %ebp
  mov %esp %ebp

  // compound_statement (function instructions)

  pop %ebp
  ret
```

As the `compound_statement` rule will be called **before** `function_definition`, I can't `fprintf()` function instructions directly in its semantic rules. However, I can't define any `streamstring` in Yacc types neither (see: [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932298/simple-string-passing-through-nodes-in-bison-yacc/8932330)).

So how should I do to put function instructions in a string (easily, not using `strcat` which would be a mess on a memory-allocation side) and then wrap them by the previous ASM instructions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably write that rule as:

```
function_definition:
    type_name declarator
        { fprintf(..function prefix code..); }
    compound_statement
        { fprintf(..function suffix code..); }
;
```

and continue to have the rules for compound_statement output code directly.  The problem is that depending on the rest of your grammar, this might introduce shift/reduce or reduce/reduce conflicts, as the embedded action introduces an extra null reduction (to run the action code) before parsing the compound_statement.

Comment: That's what Simon Ritcher suggested with "mid-rule", and it seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

- you can either build an object that contains a representation of the function body inside the code for the `compound_statement` rule, which is then passed as an argument to the `function_definition` rule's code, *or*
- you can use the GNU extension for mid-rule code.

Comment: So there is no way to get child nodes' output in `compound_statement` ? Making a representation would be very hard to do...

Comment: mid-rule code is a standard yacc feature, not a GNU extension.  However, using it can introduce shift/reduce or reduce/reduce conflicts.

Comment: You can use "string with generated output" as a representation.